# Select a subset of an object type cell in panda Dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, subset, cell

I try to select a subset of the object type column cells with str.split(pat="'")

```
dataset['pictures'].str.split(pat=",")
```

I want to get the values of the numbers 40092 and 39097 and the two dates of the pictures as two columns ID and DATE but as result I get one column consisting of NaNs.

```
'pictures' column:
{"col1":"40092","picture_date":"2017-11-06"}
{"col1":"39097","picture_date":"2017-10-31"}
...
```

Comment: use `dataset['pictures'].iloc[x]`

Comment: @Infinity. With iloc you can only select a specific cell but I need to split this cell into two different cells containing only the ID number and the date.

Comment: how about `df2 = pd.concat([df['ID'], df['date']], axis = 1)`

Comment: The columns ID en date do not exist yet I need to create them out of this one column 'pictures'. The challenge is to snip them out of this long string and leave out the unnecessary parts between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies but I solved it by loading the 'pictures' column from the dataset into a list:

```
picturelist= dataset['pictures'].values.tolist()
```

And afterwards creating a dataframe of the list made from the column pictures and concat it with the original dataset without the picture column

```
two_new_columns = pd.Dataframe(picturelist)
new_dataset = pd.concat(dataset, two_new_columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I understood from your question:

You have a pandas Dataframe with one of the columns containing json strings (or any other string that need to be parsed into multiple columns)

E.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pictures': [
    '{"col1":"40092","picture_date":"2017-11-06"}',
    '{"col1":"39097","picture_date":"2017-10-31"}']
     })
```

You want to parse the two elements ('col1' and 'picture_date') into two separate columns for further processing (or perhaps just one of them)

Define a function for parsing the row:

```
import json

def parse_row(r):
  j=json.loads(r['pictures'])
  return j['col1'],j['picture_date']
```

And use Pandas `DataFrame.apply()` method as follows

```
df1=df.apply(parse_row, axis=1,result_type='expand')
```

The result is a new dataframe with two columns - each containing the parsed data:

```
        0           1
 0  40092  2017-11-06
 1  39097  2017-10-31
```

If you need just one column you can return a single element from parse_row (instead of a two element tuple in the above example) and just use `df.apply(parse_row)`.

If the values are not in json format, just modify `parse_row` accordingly (Split, convert string to numbers, etc.)